# Is it possible to create VisualBrush from String?

Tags: c#, wpf, visualbrush

I think my question is selfexplanatory but to elaborate a little bit here is the case.

I want to assign value to `Brush` property at runtime. I am assigning it `VisualBrush` whose key I get from db by

```
Application.Current.FindResource("Key_Passed_from_DB");
```

However I have been asked to populate it from string in case that key is not available in application

for e.g. from db i will be passed

```
<Grid><Path Data="M404....">........</Grid>
```

Can this be converted to `VisualBrush` and assigned to my Brush property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Parse` Xaml strings into elements as long as you have the required namespaces (or add them before parsing).

Then you can apply your parsed WPF element to a `VisualBrush`

**Working Example:**

```
string elementString = "<Grid xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" >  <Button /> </Grid>";

Visual result = XamlReader.Parse(elementString) as Visual;

VisualBrush myBrush = new VisualBrush(result);
```